# use mounted volume as entrypoint in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I have a go project (in the directory cmd) that I'm spinning up through docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  my-image:
    build:
      context: .
    image: my_image
    volumes:
      - cmd:/cmd
    depends_on:
      - deps
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    entrypoint: ["go", "run", "./cmd/main.go"]
```

However, I keep getting this message:

```
 stat ./cmd/main.go: no such file or directory
```

is there a way I can mount the cmd directory as a volume and use a file in that as the entrypoint?

Comment: If you just want to run your Go application without building a reusable image out of it, you don't need Docker; just `go build` your application on the host system and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a number of things:

- don't use `go run` (it's meant for the most trivial of use cases and will burn you later) - use `go build` always
- `go build` your `go` binary into a docker image - there's plenty of [resources on how to do this](https://docs.docker.com/language/golang/build-images/)
- update your `docker-compose.yaml` to reference this precompiled image

---

Back to your mount issue: if you want your containers - especially in `docker compose` - to mount local mounts, use fully qualified paths:

```
volumes:
  - /Users/me/some/path/cmd:/cmd
```

this will ensure the `compose` can be run from anywhere - and there's no confusion as to where the local mount is.